# React Type Mutation response feedback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have 1 file that is calling component file with the mutation function, the submit function works well but I cant pass the result to the call function in the mutate response, is there anyway I can pass the mutation success response?

change-email.tsx

```
const AccountEmails: React.FC = () => {
  const { mutate: updateUserEmail, isLoading } = useUpdateUserEmailMutation();
  const { data } = useUserQuery();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const {
    register,
    getValues,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<UpdateUserType>({
    defaultValues,
  });
  function onSubmit(input: UpdateUserType) {
    updateUserEmail(input); // need to get response if error or succeed?????
  }
```

component updateEmail.tsx

```
import { useMutation } from "react-query";
export interface UpdateUserType {
  email: string;
}
async function updateUserEmail(input: UpdateUserType) {
  return http.patch(API_ENDPOINTS.UPDATE_EMAIL, input);
}
export const useUpdateUserEmailMutation = () => {
  return useMutation((input: UpdateUserType) => updateUserEmail(input), {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log(data, "Update User Email success response");
    },
    onError: (data) => {
      console.log(data, "Update User Email error response");
    },
  });
};
```

thank you!

Comment: Where are you importing useMutation from? I mean, which library are you using?

Comment: @maxpsz I am using react-query for it import { useMutation } from "react-query";

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it using :

`isSuccess` and `isError` variable and that will determine the success or error

thanks!